# Apply mask before computing metrics between 2 images with skimage

Tags: python, image, mask, metrics, scikit-image

I am comparing in Python, 2 images A and B by computing various metrics with skimage.measure module, Let's say for example the structural similarity index with compare_ssim(A, B).

I would like to apply a binary mask image C, to only take into account array indexes where the C mask is different to zero when computing metrics between A and B.

Is there a way to apply this mask with skimage.measure (or any other module), or do I have to reimplement those metrics myself to do it ?

Thank you !